# React-navigation - how to get user confirmation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing a react-native app with a bottom-tab-navigator. On certain navigation actions I'd like to get user confirmation before proceeding (so that the user doesn't lose their changes).

I'm using getStateForAction() to block navigation (per https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/routers.html#blocking-navigation-actions) if the user cancels the navigation:

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction;
AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if (action.type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE
    &&  state) {
        let previousScreen = state.routes[state.index].routeName;
        let currentScreen = action.routeName;

        if (previousScreen === 'Screen2') {
            (async () => {
                const confirm = await confirmDialog('Abandon Screen2?');
                if (!confirm) {
                    return null; // block navigation
                }
            })();
        }
    }

    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
}

async function confirmDialog(title) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Alert.alert(
            title,
            null,
            [
                { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => { resolve(false) }},
                { text: 'Ok', onPress: () => { resolve(true) }},
            ],
            { cancelable: false });
    })
}
```

This almost works ... except that when getStateForAction() executes the async block and presents the confirm-dialog it doesn't wait for a response. Instead it goes ahead with the navigation regardless (and ignores the user's answer).

Is there a way of making this work, or a better way of getting user confirmation for a navigation action?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution: it requires access to the navigator, so I'm passing this as a navigation parameter in each screen:

**Screen.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ screenNav: this.props.navigation });
}
```

I can then block navigation by default, and navigate only if/when the user confirms, by modifying *getStateForAction()*:

```
AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if (action.type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE
    &&  state) {
        let screenNav = state.routes[state.index].params.screenNav;
        let previousScreen = state.routes[state.index].routeName;
        let currentScreen = action.routeName;

        if (previousScreen === 'Screen2' && !state.isConfirmed) {
            (async () => {
                const confirm = await confirmDialog('Abandon Screen2?');
                if (confirm) {
                    state.isConfirmed = true;
                    screenNav.navigate(nextScreen); // navigate on confirmation
                }
            })();
            return null; // block navigation by default
        }

        state.isConfirmed = false;
    }

    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
}
```

Note: flag *state.isConfirmed* is necessary to avoid an infinite loop as `screenNav.navigate(nextScreen)` immediately calls *getStateForAction()* again with the same parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to use redux. Save the data on redux and on click functionality check the condition whether you need to render the screen or not!